# which language or tool will be better for reading a video file

Tags: video, avi

Actually I want to know how to read the pixel (raw) data of a avi video file.

How can I put these pixels (raw data) inside another video format so that I'm able to play it using another media player ?

Which language is good at manipulating video streamings of files? By good I mean "have good / free libraries" and "have a easy learning curve".

Comment: if you ask for a language why did you tag the question as 'java'?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to understand many concepts on JPEG, i kindly request you to read the following libraries source code from this link .The Ogle DVD Player

http://www.dtek.chalmers.se/groups/dvd/downloads.shtml

```
 1. libjpeg
 2. libdvdread
 3. ogle-0.9.2.tar.gz
 4. ogle_gui-0.9.2.tar.gz
```

Extract ogle-0.9.2.tar.gz which is the core library, there you have a folder called mpeg2_video , a file called `videostream.c,screenshot.c` .This will help in getting started.
Also be aware in Maths such as Fast Fourier Transform.